# IBOutlet always nil

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xib

I've already looked at all the other entries for this question. I have been stuck for a while on a problem I have been unable to solve, any suggestion for an avenue of approach would be sincerely appreciated.

I have a moderately large app that allocs a window controller then loads a window using an XIB containing a single window which contains an `AVPlayerView` that was placed in the window. The `AVPlayerView` is wired to an `IBOutlet` called `playerView`. The window loads when it is supposed to and then an `AVPlayer` is created with a URL and is to be assigned to the player of the `AVPlayerView`, however I always find that the `IBOutlet` `playerView` is always `nil` at the point of trying to make the assignment. I cannot figure out why the `IBOutlet` is `nil`. Another anomaly is that the `AVPlayerWindow` will not become key when so ordered even though there are no other windows on the screen. I know for a fact that I have the outlet wired up in the XIB. Any thoughts?

There  are 11,000 lines of code in the app. Here is the tiny portion that attempts to attach the player to the `AVPlayerView`.

```
        fileURL = [self prepareStringAndBecomeAURL:filePath isDirectory:NO needFileURL:NO];

    //    thePlayer = [self prepareToPlay:fileURL];
        thePlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:fileURL];
        if (thePlayer == nil) {
            [self popUpErrorMessageWithoutCode:@"Unable to create a video player."];
        } else {
            playerView.player = thePlayer;
            if (thePlayer != nil) {
                [theMainWindow orderOut:self];
                [self showMoviesWindow:self];
                [self performSelector:@selector(continueHandleMovieSelected) withObject:nil afterDelay:1]; // wait for window to appear
            }
        }
    }

    - (void)continueHandleMovieSelected
    {
        [playerView.player play];
    }
```

No, no exceptions.

Window controller and nib are created in another module, an AppController:

```
    - (IBAction)showMoviePlayerWindow:(id)sender
    {
        if (![self myMoviePlayerWindowController]) {
            myMoviePlayerWindowController = [[MoviePlayerWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"MoviePlayer"];
            [self set_myMoviePlayerWindowController:myMoviePlayerWindowController];
        }
        [[[self myMoviePlayerWindowController] window] center];
        [[[self myMoviePlayerWindowController] window] makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
        [[self myMoviePlayerWindowController] showWindow:self];
    }
```

Comment: Post a [mre] please.

Comment: There are 11,000 lines of code in this app. Here is the tiny portion that attempts to attach the player to the AVPlayerView:

Comment: I don't know if that little bit of code will help but I really think it's a different problem than this bit of code. It's the IBOutlet, playerView that is nil. In a completely different test app to see how the player works, the outlet is not nil when I breakpoint on this similar code.

Comment: Any exceptions?

Comment: How are the window controller and window instantiated?

Comment: The window is loaded from the nib in the AppController by the code just shown.

Comment: When is `playerView` `nil`? Is `myMoviePlayerWindowController` a property or an ivar? What does `set_myMoviePlayerWindowController:` do?

Comment: playerView is nil when I attempt to set playerViewer.player to the player inited by the URL. I have not yet learned Swift or ARC so I still code in objective-C. set_myMoviePlayerWindowController is a call to save the moviePlayerWindowController to a value to be recalled later.

Comment: When do you attempt to set playerViewer.player to the player inited by the URL? From where is the code called?

Comment: It's in the first code segment. The player is created with the fileURL (in breakpoint tracing, the player is created). When attempting to assign the player to the playerView, that's when the IBOutlet (wired to the player view in the window) is nil.

Comment: Which method is the first code segment? If it isn't an AppKit method, from which AppKit method is it called? Is the test app the same?

Comment: In the code segment above, the second post, the window controller is allocated with the nib which has the window in it via Xcode.

Comment: In which method is the outlet 'nil'? Maybe you're using it too early.

Comment: In the first code snippet the showWindow launches the XIB window containing the player. Then the performSelector waits 1 second for the window to appear then continues the code which should have the outlet connected by then but even if I wait 2 seconds, it doesn't help.